# How to ensure the text position importing a draw from Inkscape?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, import, inkscape

I'm doing my draws using inkscape, but when put them in LaTeX, the text appears randomly. The following picture is the draw that I made in inkscape

[image: Draw from inkscape]

The code that I use to put it in LaTeX is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\def\svgwidth{0.4\textwidth}
\input{Paletas.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```

And the result is this

[image: Paletas LaTeX]

I tried to change the width, but the text still being away from the center.

Anyone can help me??

EDIT:
I'm uploading the code of Paletas.pdf_tex

```
%% Creator: Inkscape 0.91_64bit, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'Paletas.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{258.49033203bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,1.7028689)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{Paletas.pdf}}%
    \put(-0.00468465,0.01184764){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$L_{1}=4,3\ cm$}}}%
    \put(0.18499846,0.2154351){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$i=1$}}}%
    \put(0.18499846,0.60902075){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$i=2$}}}%
    \put(0.18499846,1.0026064){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$i=3$}}}%
    \put(0.18499846,1.39619206){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$i=4$}}}%
    \put(0.59258631,0.21557111){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$b=1,6\ cm$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: Well, you forgot to upload `Paletas.pdf_tex`.

Comment: `\put(-0.00468465,0.01184764){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$L_{1}=4,3\ cm$}}}%` See that line? Change the very first value from minus point something to point one. Play with the value a bit.

Comment: Is the text `$L_{1}= ... $` [and the rest] set as `Align center` (i.e. centered text) in Inkscape? Can't test now.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Johannes_B and @alwaysask. I tried the @alwaysask's way. I went to the inkscape file, and centered the text using the distribution tool, but I used the center text option from text controls (Shift+Ctrl+T), and it works